# How to fix 'Job for bluetooth.service failed' error and enable Bluetooth on parrot?

Tags: linux, error-handling, terminal, bluetooth, parrot-os

```
$ sudo systemctl restart bluetooth.service
[sudo] password for kartik:
Job for bluetooth.service failed because the control process exited with error code. 
See "systemctl status bluetooth.service" and "journalctl -xeu bluetooth.service" for details.
```

I am not able to run any command like restart, start , enable .

After this error i tried both `systemctl status bluetooth.service` and `journalctl -xeu bluetooth.service` but i was unable to solve this problem.

```
$systemctl status bluetooth.service
× bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; preset: enabled) 
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2023-05-07 21:14:33 IST; 4min 19s ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
  Process: 6824 ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd -E (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 6824 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC) CPU: 930us

May 07 21:14:33 parrot systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

```
Subject: Unit failed
Defined-By: systemd
Support: https://www.debian.org/support
The unit bluetooth.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'. May 07 21:14:33 parrot systemd[1]: Failed to start bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service.

Subject: A start job for unit bluetooth.service has failed
Defined-By: systemd
Support: https://www.debian.org/support
A start job for unit bluetooth.service has finished with a failure.
The job identifier is 5343 and the job result is failed.
```

please help me in this problem.

Comment: The error messages are suggesting that `bluetoothd` is not starting. This could be caused by many issues such as wrong path to file or wrong permissions on file. Have you tried running`bluetoothd` from the command line?

Comment: I tried , i also tried to reinstall bluez but it not making a Bluetooth/bluetoothd folder in usr/lib directory

Comment: If you do `which bluetoothd`, where does it say that it is installed?

Comment: /usr/sbin/bluetoothd

Comment: And `/usr/sbin/bluetoothd` might be a link to `/usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd`. Either way, you need to update `/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service` so that `ExecStart` is pointing at the correct location. Then do a `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` and `sudo service bluetooth restart`